# Differentiate between two times using php

Tags: php

I am currently developing an online mcq examination system. Here, when user submits form (after completing an exam), the $total_time_of_paper and $user_time also submitted by the hidden field. After form submission, it will calculate the time taken by the user.

For example, if $total_time_of_paper  = 10 mins, when user submits form, $user_time = 3 mins 27 secs, then I need output = 6 mins 33 secs.

Please note, timer calculates time from 10 to 0.

I tried date_diff(), but not get right result.

```
$date1=date_create( $total_time_of_paper . ' : 00'); 
$date2=date_create($user_time ); 
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2); 
echo $diff->i . ' : ' . $diff->s;
```

Any hint to use this function correctly, or any other php function.

Comment: `date_diff()` should work for this, what is wrong with the result that gives you?

Comment: rickdenhaan is right, so post your code.  Also search for PHP time arithmetic, you will see a lot of threads on that.

Comment: ok. please wait. see the code below

$date1=date_create( $total_time_of_paper .  ' : 00');
$date2=date_create($user_time );
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->i . ' : ' . $diff->s;

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee What is the result of that code with your values? Note that in `date_create()` there should **NOT** be spaces in `' : 00'`

Comment: Hi rickdenhaan, this gives me following errors.

Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exam\user_home.php on line 360

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\exam\user_home.php on line 361

Comment: plz give me some hint. i only want minute and second calculation. not year month or any other

Comment: That error means `date_create()` failed on `$date1`. Can you run `print_r(date_get_last_errors())` on the line before you create `$date2` to see why it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this but based upon what you have, try this...

```
$total_time_of_paper = 10;
$user_time = '00:03:33';

$date1=date_create( '00:'.$total_time_of_paper . ':00');
$date2=date_create($user_time );
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);

echo $diff->i . ':' . $diff->s;
```

The main thing is getting your times for $user_time and $total_time_of_paper in the correct format of '00:00:00';

As you are only dealing in times, you could also use this...

```
$total_time_of_paper = '00:10:00';
$user_time = '00:03:33';

$time_1 = strtotime($total_time_of_paper);
$time_2 = strtotime($user_time);
$time_diff = $time_1 - $time_2;
$time_remaining = date('i:s', $time_diff);
```

And you could turn that into a function and as you are using codeigniter ( as per your many tags... ) you could turn this into a helper function.

Comment: Both answers working like rocks, You save my valuable hours. thank you so much. :)